How to perform LCA with imputed datasets using GLCA
I'm preparing a LCA (LCR) analysis and are trying to learn how to use imputed data for the analyses.
I have previously used mice for regression analyses and then the procedure has been quite simple. However, this procedure seems to not work for GLCA. Any suggestions?

# Step 1: Simulate a Sample Dataset
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
# Simulating a dataset with missing data in covariates
data <- data.frame(
var1 = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), # LCA variable 1
var2 = sample(1:4, n, replace = TRUE), # LCA variable 2
var3 = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE), # LCA variable 3
covariate1 = rnorm(n),  # Continuous covariate with missing data
covariate2 = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE) # Categorical covariate with missing data
)
# Introduce missing data in covariates
data$covariate1[sample(1:n, 30)] <- NA  # 15% missing data
data$covariate2[sample(1:n, 20)] <- NA  # 10% missing data

imputed_data <- mice(data, m = 5, method = "pmm", seed = 500) #Imputed data

lca_model <- with(imputed_data, glca(nclass = 3, item(var1, var2, var3) ~ covariate1, covariate2, n.init = 1)) #LCA-modelling

summary(lca_model) #This returns the error "Error: No tidy method for objects of class glca"

summary(pool(lca_model)) #This returns the error "Error: No tidy method for objects of class glca
#In addition: Warning message:
 # In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed.



As the error implies, there is no method (i.e. "version" of the function pool) that handles LCA models. Nevertheless, it is statistically ok to pool any statistic across imputations, as long as they are expected to be normally distribution (google "Rubin's rules" about that). Look at this answer to a similar problem for an explanation on how to do it.
